# Filtering a simple number array on vue

Tags: vue.js, filter

I have a simple number array generated at random that is rendered by a `v-for`, I also want to be able to filter it by writing the desired numbers in a input, I do this by using the vanilla JS `filter()` method. However it returns the error

```
TypeError: "num.includes is not a function"
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong, here's the html:

```js
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        numberArray: [],
        searching: ''
      },
      methods: {
        random() {
          this.numberArray = Array.from({
            length: 40
          }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40));
        },
        search(){
        return this.numberArray.filter((num) => num.includes(this.searching));
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

 <div id="app">
      <button @click="random()">
    Generate
    </button>
      <hr>
        <input type="search" v-model="searching" placeholder="search">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="num in search">
          {{ num }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Looks like search should be a computed value instead of a method, and that 'this' is not referring to what you think it is inside of the search function. I'll write an answer up quick and watch for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes()` is a function defined on strings and arrays, not numbers.

Also `search` should be a computed property instead of a method.

Did you mean to do this:

```js
computed: {
  search() {
    return this.numberArray.filter(num => String(num).includes(this.searching));
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this.searching return the appropriate value or is the context of `this` now limited to within the function?

Comment: Yes; you used a fat arrow function (`=>`), so `this` will be bound to the component instance as expected.

Comment: Indeed this and moving search to `computed ` did the trick. Thank you.